# Error with HMAC and newlines in R "digest" package

Tags: r, hmac

I am attempting to implement R code to interface with Amazon's Alexa Web Information Service. The authentication system requires HMAC hashing of text against a secret key, but there seems to be a problem with the "digest" package when the text contains newlines.

Minimal example in R:

```
library(digest)
hmac("foo", "Hello", algo="sha256")
```

returns `fa687477a49ebadb72eb1103db6128061437a2501db7ee7f0cbbb79ceaa2fcfc`, while

```
hmac("foo", "Hello\nGoodbye", algo="sha256")
```

returns `eaf58b106ffdbb4af976b6b87e14d231e090f7bc144f0b56f06980c827444288`.

If I check against http://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html, the first case gives the same hash, but the second gives `967b28392b2ddc871bb69417e916fa619c935840cc2b9507ecf4da3f748bd1ba`.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of newlines! It appears that the website uses windows style line endings when you include a newline in the text. So you can get that "967b" value if you do

```
hmac("foo","Hello\r\nGoodbye",algo="sha256")
# [1] "967b28392b2ddc871bb69417e916fa619c935840cc2b9507ecf4da3f748bd1ba"
```

I'm guessing you might be on a Mac or a linux machine. I think the `\n` character is supposed to resolve to the correct value depending on OS. Perhaps doing

```
hmac("foo","Hello\x0D\x0AGoodbye",algo="sha256")
```

might be better to be explicit about the line ending you need to do in the file on all systems.

Comment: Yup. That's the problem with the specific issue here, however, it seems that my problem goes deeper than this. The equivalent Perl code from Amazon's site (http://aws.amazon.com/code/AWIS/394) isn't giving the same thing as R, even with no newlines. Back to the drawing board...

Comment: So Perl disagrees with the website and R?

Comment: I solved the problem: turns out I was doing the base64 encoding incorrectly. Here's the right way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251632/amazon-product-api-with-r

Comment: So was `hmac` doing something other than base64 encoding by default?

Comment: Sorry, it's confusing because I haven't given you all of the information for my actual code. Amazon's example Perl code uses `hmac_sha256_base64()` from `Digest::SHA`. In R, this requires two steps: doing the HMAC using `hmac()`, then the base64 encoding (in my case using `base64()` from `RCurl`). My problem was that I didn't use the `raw = T` option to `hmac()`, so the hashes were not agreeing with what was coming out of Perl (and weren't authenticating on Amazon...).

Answer (score 11):

So, while MrFlick did answer my specific question, the real issue was deeper. The whole question was prompted by a disagreement between Perl's `hmac_sha256_base64()` and R.

It turned out that I was using R incorrectly. `hmac()` returns hex code, not base64, so an additional step is needed. However, it seems that the `base64()` function in `RCurl` requires a vector of bytes, not a concatenated string. I illustrate below.

What I was doing (WRONG):

```
require(digest)
require(RCurl)

> hmac("foo", "Hello", algo="sha256")
[1] "fa687477a49ebadb72eb1103db6128061437a2501db7ee7f0cbbb79ceaa2fcfc"

> base64(hmac("foo", "Hello", algo="sha256"))
[1] "ZmE2ODc0NzdhNDllYmFkYjcyZWIxMTAzZGI2MTI4MDYxNDM3YTI1MDFkYjdlZTdmMGNiYmI3OWNlYWEyZmNmYw=="
attr(,"class")
[1] "base64"
```

What I should have done (CORRECT):

```
> hmac("foo", "Hello", algo="sha256", raw = T)
[1] fa 68 74 77 a4 9e ba db 72 eb 11 03 db 61 28 06 14 37 a2 50 1d b7 ee 7f 0c bb b7 9c ea a2 fc fc

> base64(hmac("foo", "Hello", algo="sha256", raw = T))
[1] "+mh0d6Seutty6xED22EoBhQ3olAdt+5/DLu3nOqi/Pw="
attr(,"class")
[1] "base64"
```

Rather different, no?

The latter agrees with the Perl, and (more importantly) it actually authenticates correctly on Amazon Web Services. :-)