# Return Product Data from Amazon Product API Using R

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, api

I would like to use R to extract product information from the [Amazon Product API](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/). As suggested by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251632/amazon-product-api-with-r) and [Amazon's Signed Requests Helper](http://associates-amazon.s3.amazonaws.com/signed-requests/helper/index.html), I'm using the following R code:

```
library("RCurl")

nvp <- list("Service"="AWSECommerceService",
            "Version"="2011-08-01",
            "AssociateTag"="PutYourAssociateTagHere",
            "Operation"="ItemSearch",
            "SearchIndex"="Books",
            "Keywords"="harry+potter",
            "Timestamp"="2020-02-26T11:25:14.000Z",
            "AWSAccessKeyId"="XXX")                    # "XXX" needs to be replaced by the Access Key

getURL(nvp)

# AWSECommerceService               2011-08-01  PutYourAssociateTagHere               ItemSearch                    Books             harry+potter 2020-02-26T11:25:14.000Z                      XXX 
#                  ""                       ""                       ""                       ""                       ""                       ""                       ""                       ""
```

As you can see, the getURL function is just returning empty characters. Afters hours of searching I am still not able to get any other output, no matter how I change the parameters of the previous code.

How could I modify the previous code to return product data from the Amazon Product API?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Signed Requests Helper](http://associates-amazon.s3.amazonaws.com/signed-requests/helper/index.html) you provided, the sample url is as follows:

```
http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&Version=2011-08-01&AssociateTag=PutYourAssociateTagHere&Operation=ItemSearch&SearchIndex=Books&Keywords=harry+potter
```

Some modifications are therefore needed to the nvp list you provided above. These changes are:
 1. Put each parameter inside a string (e.g. 'Version=2011-08-01', instead of 'version' = '2011-08-01'
 2. Ensure that the formatting maps (for example in the sample URL, Version is preceded by
&, so we make sure this is added.
 3. Finally, we need a base url to paste this onto (this is everything in the sample url before Service).

```
nvp = c("Service=AWSECommerceService",
       "&Version=2011-08-01",
       "&AssociateTag=PutYourAssociateTagHere",
       "&Operation=ItemSearch",
       "&SearchIndex=Books",
       "&Keywords=harry+potter",
      "&Timestamp=2020-02-26T11:25:14.000Z",
      "&AWSAccessKeyId = XXX")
base_url = "http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?"
```

We then need to paste together base_url and nvp to make our url

```
amazon_url = paste0(base_url, paste(nvp, collapse=''))
```

This gives the url we can pass to getURL. If you pass the associate tag/AWS Access Key ID these should work, I currently get a 'must contain AWS Access Key ID error'.

[This is obviously very manual approach, if you wanted to be more progamatic about searching you could do:

```
AWSAccessKeyID = '1234'
keywords = 'harry+potter'
```

These can then be passed to the paste, with minor modifications

```
nvp = list("Service=AWSECommerceService",
               "&Version=2011-08-01",
               "&AssociateTag=PutYourAssociateTagHere",
               "&Operation=ItemSearch",
               "&SearchIndex=Books",
               "&Keywords=", keywords,
               "&Timestamp=2020-02-26T11:25:14.000Z",
               "&AWSAccessKeyId=" AWSAccessKeyID 
                )
amazon_url = paste0(base_url, paste(nvp, collapse=''))
```

]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response. Unfortunately, I receive the error message `MissingParameter - The request must contain the parameter Signature.` when I use your code. When I add a signature as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251632/amazon-product-api-with-r), I receive the error message `RequestThrottled - You are submitting requests too quickly. Please retry your requests at a slower rate.` [This](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?start=0&threadID=297508&tstart=0) thread points on a minimum of sales. However, we definitely generate enough sales.

Comment: Was this a new key pair? It seems like the Amazon Support team response said that they took 48hours to work after registering (assuming that you have required sales). I imagine it'd send an invalid signature error if your signature/keys were completely wrong.... Have you tried re-running?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! The keys are older than 1 year, so this can not be the reason. We also managed to access the API with Python, so the keys are definitely not the problem. Please let me know in case you have any further suggestions, since I would highly prefer to work with R instead of Python.

Comment: Just a thought; if you enter your Key & secret access key here at the signed requests helper, what does the URL look like? (you can do it at the Signed Requests Helper link above. You may need to remove your signature, but you can compare how the signature looks on the site to the one generated by your code perhaps?

Comment: If I use the URL returned by the Signed Requests Helper I get the same error message. I assume something must be wrong with the input parameters, i.e. some parts are wrong or missing.

Comment: To clarify; you put both your associate tag into the AssociateTag parameter (line three of nvp), and then your signed AWS key into your AWSAccessKeyId parameter? Sorry, I've not used this API before hence tricky to work it out...

Comment: Yes, I got both of these values from my Amazon Partner account. The associate tag is the first tracking ID I got from Amazon and looks like this: XXXXX-21. The access key was generated more than 1 year ago and looks like this: AL5AJXXXXXXX. Both of these tags/IDs are working with certain Wordpress plugins and they are also working when I'm accessing the API via Python, so I guess they must be correct.